# A JavaScript alert or dialog with a combo box

Tags: javascript

This looks fairly simple, but 30 minutes of googling took me nowhere. :-(

How do I create a simple JavaScript dialog / alert with a combo box so my user can select a value before submitting? I am using this for a rejection reason so user clicks on reject button and must select a reason from a combo box inside an alert / dialog popup window before submitting.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't something already made for that? JQuery? Prototype? It looks like something basic to be re-used over and over again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if  [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) suits you. Check example number 17.

Comment: Example 17 has no combo box and nothing to select, just text.

Answer (score 3):

The inbuilt JavaScript dialog functions `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` can't do this. Rather than use a "real" popup instead, which creates a button in the taskbar, try creating a window-like `<div>` element as an in-page popup, with the combo box.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with alert(), prompt(), or confirm() methods. You would have to create a popup or popin to host the combo box (select).